# How to delete DF rows based on multiple column conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's an example of DF:

```
        EC1     EC2     CDC      L1      L2      L3      L4      L5      L6      VNF
0    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]   [1, 0]
1    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]   [0, 1]
2    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [-1, 0]
3    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, -1]
4    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   [1, 0]
5    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   [0, 1]
6    [1, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]  [-1, 0]
```

How to delete those rows where df['VNF'] = [-1, 0] or [0, -1] and df['EC1'], df['EC2'] and df['CDC'] has a value of 0 in the same index position as the -1 in df['VNF'])?

The expected result would be:

```
        EC1     EC2     CDC      L1      L2      L3      L4      L5      L6      VNF
0    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]   [1, 0]
1    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]   [0, 1]
2    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   [1, 0]
3    [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   [0, 1]
4    [1, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]  [-1, 0]
```

Here's the constructor for the DataFrame:

```
data = {'EC1': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 0]],
 'EC2': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
 'CDC': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]],
 'L1': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
 'L2': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
 'L3': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
 'L4': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]],
 'L5': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]],
 'L6': [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]],
 'VNF': [[1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0]]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode every column of `df`, then identify the elements satisfying the first (sum of "VNF" values must be -1) and second condition and filter out the elements that satisfy both conditions to create `temp`. Then since each cell must have two elements, you can count whether each index contains 2 elements by transforming `count`, then filter the rows with two indices and `groupby` the index and aggregate to list:

```
exploded = df.explode(df.columns.tolist())
first_cond = exploded.groupby(level=0)['VNF'].transform('sum').eq(-1)
second_cond = exploded['VNF'].eq(-1) & exploded['EC1'].eq(0) & exploded['EC2'].eq(0) & exploded['CDC'].eq(0)

temp = exploded[~(first_cond & second_cond)]
out = temp[temp.groupby(level=0)['VNF'].transform('count').gt(1)].groupby(level=0).agg(list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
      EC1     EC2     CDC      L1      L2      L3      L4      L5      L6  \
0  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]   
1  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]   
2  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   
3  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   
4  [1, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   

       VNF  
0   [1, 0]  
1   [0, 1]  
2   [1, 0]  
3   [0, 1]  
4  [-1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension to find which indexes to drop might help see the conditions more directly:

```
columns = df.EC1, df.EC2, df.CDC, df.VNF

inds_to_drop = [iloc
                for iloc, (ec1, ec2, cdc, vnf) in enumerate(zip(*columns))
                if vnf == [-1, 0] or vnf == [0, -1]
                if all(val[idx] == 0
                       for idx in (vnf.index(-1),) for val in (ec1, ec2, cdc))]

new_df = df.drop(df.index[inds_to_drop])
```

to get

```
>>> new_df

      EC1     EC2     CDC      L1      L2      L3      L4      L5      L6      VNF
0  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]   [1, 0]
1  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]   [0, 1]
4  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   [1, 0]
5  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]   [0, 1]
6  [1, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 0]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]  [-1, 0]
```

---

The list comprehension starts with the outer for loop over the column values and their integer indexes:

```
for iloc, (ec1, ec2, cdc, vnf) in enumerate(zip(*columns))
```

Then the first condition to drop kicks in:

> df['VNF'] = [-1, 0] or [0, -1]

```
if vnf == [-1, 0] or vnf == [0, -1]
```

And the second condition:

> df['EC1'], df['EC2'] and df['CDC'] has a value of 0 in the same index position as the -1 in df['VNF'])

```
if all(val[idx] == 0 for idx in (vnf.index(-1),) for val in (ec1, ec2, cdc))
```

Here, we check if *all* of the values of 3 columns satisfy the criterion. A trick here is 1-turn loop `for idx in (vnf.index(-1),)` so as to evaluate the index of -1 only once (compare with `val[vnf.index(-1)] for val in (ec1, ec2, cdc)`; less efficient).

Then the list is comprehended with the integer index locations of rows to drop:

```
>>> inds_to_drop
[2, 3]
```

If you have a RangeIndex, i.e., 0..N-1 kind of index, then you can directly say `new_df = df.drop(inds_to_drop)`. But if custom index (e.g., `["a", "d", "e", "f"]`), we lookup the real index labels with `df.index[inds_to_drop]` and then drop (would be `"e", "f"`); this covers all cases.